# unit testing static objects

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have classes that are configurable via composition.

For example:

###### objects.cpp:

```
dog::config cfg = { .bark = loud; }
static dog my_dog(cfg);
```

In order to be MISRA compliant (3-4-1), the object `dog` requires the `static` storage specifier.

It is easy to unit test the *class* `dog`, and I can provide it with whatever configuration I want.

The problem is, in my production project, I want to test `my_dog` to ensure it was configured correctly, and that the way in which it was configured works as expected. In addition, this will allow `dog` to interact with other configurable objects such as `newspaper`, and allow for some higher-level testing.

I am not sure if this is possible without modifying the `objects.cpp` to include test code, which I don't want to do. If I were to remove `static` it would be easy, but I can't do that. I also have multiple instances of `dog` with different configurations, so I don't make the configuration variables reside internally somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make a function to get `dog`'s cfg, so you can use the same in UTs?

Comment: If your testcode doesn't have to be fully MISRA compliant you don't need static instances in your tests right, so I would just create local instances of a configured dog per test case.  Note : For the static dog I would use this pattern https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton. So you can define the access to the singletons in a header file and share that between test and production code if you need to.

Comment: Given that `dog` is _an object_, and there is only a single MISRA release for C++, MISRA C++:2008, are you referring to the correct rule? _"Rule 3-3-2: If a function has internal linkage then all re-declarations shall include the static storage class specifier."_

Comment: Not sure where your `my_dog` is being statically constructed (global scope? function scope? class scope?), but you could do `static dog my_dog([]{ return dog::config{ .bark = loud; }; }());` to avoid the `cfg` which is only used in the construction of `my_dog`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in th comments you can create a static access proxy to you object:

```
static dog *dogProxy::getDog() { 
    static dog my_dog(cfg);
    return &dog;
}
...

dog *uut = dogProxy::getDog();
```

But this can have a bad effect to your code. People could try to use this vor your production code. So defining a special preprocessor for test code makes sense.

```
#ifdef UNITTEST
static dog *dogProxy::getDog() { 
    static dog my_dog(cfg);
    return &dog;
}
#endif
```

Comment: that certainly would work though I'm trying to avoid adding any code for unit testing, even if it's macro-ed out. I'll keep this in mind, if it ends up being needed. thank you.